# How does Apple Watch calculate a new Smart Move Goal?

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

I've noticed that on the Monday after I get a *Perfect Week (Move)* award, my Apple Watch (SE; watchOS 7) prompts me with a new Smart Move Goal. However, this week I was perplexed to see that my proposed Smart Move Goal was unchanged from my previous move goal. I expected the watch to propose a higher goal; why didn't it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe it thought you'd bust a gut trying to achieve last week's so decided you should take some time not arriving pink & flustered before moving it up a notch ;)) [sorry, rather insulting to your health, but just as a half-truth-joke - it may, in fact be considering how much 'effort' it thought you had needed to achieve it]

Answer (score 1):

I think it takes into account by how much you beat your goal: if you're goal is 620 and you just made it (for instance 623), then it will assume that you're just about making it so it won't suggest a higher number. If you made it comfortably (say 700), then it will suggest an increase.